# JQuery replace double quotes on hidden value

Tags: jquery

I have a web application that every `keyup` sending the input to the a `input=hidden`
after that Im sending the hidden `value` to the server.

the thing is, I need to escape the quotes before it goes to the `hidden input` like that :

```
$('.textBoxSal').live('keyup', function () {
//...code...
      $('.' + cell + 'Td').html(myValue.replace('"', "&quot;") + '<input type="hidden" class="' + cell + 'Out" value="' + myValue.replace('"', "&quot;") + '"/>');
```

I dont know why, but it refuses to make it happen in the hidden input..
I even placed a `console.log` there, and the code seem to work in the `console.log`

what could be the issue?

EDIT: Heres an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/DSZm4/

Comment: First your selector is (effectively) `'.classNameTD'` (do you need a space in there (to select the `td` descendent of that class-name, or should the `td` *have* that class-name?); and `live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+ and *removed* (***entirely***) from jQuery 1.9+. Also a string passed to `replace()` will replace only the first value found, not all of the values. Without your HTML, *and* ideally a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it's hard to offer specific help.

Comment: @DavidThomas there you go :  http://jsfiddle.net/DSZm4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a global regular expression for this:

```
myValue.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: can you please add a few words about your solution?  it not seem to work, but maybe if I'll understand why you say it..

Comment: can you create fiddle for your problem??

Comment: it was partially correct.   you were right for the global regex, but the '\\"' was not OK.   I needed to come up with something like "PPPP???" and then translate it back to double quotes.

Comment: i believe you must had the pattern of `\\` in your code.